# Best way to map and objects in an array to single object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to map the **answer** property based on the type to a new single object

```
const questionsArray = [
  {
    question: `What is your name?`,
    type: "name"
  },
  {
    question: `What is your age?`,
    type: "age"
  }
]
```

Which will result to this:

```
bday = {
          name: 'Jose',
          age: '23',
        }
```

This won't work because every question will replace the previous value already set since the type will be different

Comment: can the types match with the key in the resulting object? e.g does `birthDay` have to be that or can it use the type of `day` and thus be the key `day` instead?

Comment: @NickParsons yes you are right! it can be like you say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` and use `type` as key and `answer` as value for that key

```js
const questionsArray = [  {    id: 0,    question: `What is your name?`,    answer: 'jose',    type: "name"  },  {    id: 1,    question: `What is your birth month?`,    answer: 'January',    type: "month"  },  {    id: 2,    question: `What day in were you born?`,    answer: '24',    type: "day"  },  {    id: 3,    question: `What's your email?`,    answer: 'k@k.gmail.com',    type: 'email'  }]

const res = questionsArray.reduce((ac, {type, answer}) => {
  ac[type] = answer;
  return ac;
}, {});
console.log(res)
```

As you will notice in the above way you can't use any other keys other than `type` property of array values.

If you want to have custom property names in resulting object you need to have an hash table.

```js
const questionsArray = [  {    id: 0,    question: `What is your name?`,    answer: 'jose',    type: "name"  },  {    id: 1,    question: `What is your birth month?`,    answer: 'January',    type: "month"  },  {    id: 2,    question: `What day in were you born?`,    answer: '24',    type: "day"  },  {    id: 3,    question: `What's your email?`,    answer: 'k@k.gmail.com',    type: 'email'  }]

const table = {
  day: 'birthDay',
  month: 'birthMonth'
}

const res = questionsArray.reduce((ac, {type, answer}) => {
  ac[table[type] || type] = answer;
  return ac;
}, {});
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.map()` to map each object to an new object with which has the `type` as the key and the `answer` as the value. You can then use `Object.assing()` to build one larger resulting object from this array of mapped objects:

```js
const questionsArray = [ { id: 0, question: `What is your name?`, answer: 'jose', type: "name" }, { id: 1, question: `What is your birth month?`, answer: 'January', type: "month" }, { id: 2, question: `What day in were you born?`, answer: '24', type: "day" }, { id: 3, question: `What's your email?`, answer: 'k@k.gmail.com', type: 'email' } ];

const bday = Object.assign(...questionsArray.map(({answer, type}) => ({[type]: answer})));
console.log(bday);
```

Comment: Nice combination of all the features